# Mac OS X Server: What is "Mobile Access Server"?

Tags: mac, osx-server

The Mac OS X Server homepage tells of a feature "Mobile Access Server":

http://www.apple.com/server/macosx/features/mobile-access.html

But the text is very marketingy and doesn't actually say what it does? Is it a type of VPN or a remote desktop thingy or what?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [AppleInsider](http://www.appleinsider.com/articles/09/04/24/snow_leopard_server_to_offer_low_cost_secure_mobile_access_to_iphone.html) (and my understanding of what they are saying), it's a VPN-like for accessing internal resources without the traditional overhead of VPN, using their own *"always-on"* security.

Answer (score 1):

It's a kind of secure proxy. See Chapter 9, "Working with Mobile Access Service" of the Mac OS X Server [Network Services Administration](http://images.apple.com/server/macosx/docs/Network_Services_Admin_v10.6.pdf) manual.